# vuejs - lazy loading using webpack chunks - import vs requie-resolve

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

In case of lazy loading using webpack chunks, I have found couple of ways - one using require & resolve and other one is using import.

**require & resolve way-**

```
const Home = resolve => {
  require.ensure(['components/Home/Home'], () => {
    resolve(require('components/Home/Home'));
  }, 'home');
};
```

**import way-**

```
const Home = import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ 'components/Home/Home');
```

Can someone please explain me what is difference between these 2 approaches? And when to use each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is the modern version of the first one. The second one only works with webpack >=2 .*

Unless you are using webpack 1, always use the second

*DIfferences*

They achieve the exact same thing, the only difference is that `import()` returns a Promise.